# How to read the state of check box, pull down menu, and toggle in javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to read the state of a checkbox to see if it is checked. I will also be reading the options on a pull down menu in html and I also want to read the state of a toggle if it is clicked.  I will be using a conditional to perform actions in javascript based upon these options.

Here is the code for the checkbox and pulldown menu:

checkbox html

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem">Item 1
```

pulldown menu html

```
    <form>
    Select your favorite fruit:
    <select id="mySelect">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
    </select>
    </form>
```

(I am not sure how to do the toggle)

So if I check the box and select an option from the pulldown menu, I want to
execute commands in javascript using a conditional.

What is the code to create the conditional that reads if the box is checked and reads the option selected from the pulldown menu?

I think jquery is needed to do this. How do I do this?

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ - you can start with Google, search and research, than come back with some code, [edit] show a minimal effort in resolving your own issue by creating a [mcve] - please read [ask]  - Also, if you missed it upon registering take a [tour]  PS: in **none of your questions so far** you showed any code of what you tried.

Comment: I  clarified my question. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answered most of my question. I have not figured out and tested the toggle however.

```
<html>
<div class="container">
<input type="checkbox" class="checks" value ="Apple">Apple<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checks" value ="BananaValue">Banana<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checks" value ="Carrot">Carrot<br>



<form>
  Select your favorite fruit:
  <select id="mySelect" /*onchange="run();"*/>
    <option value="apple">apple</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
  </select>
</form>

<input type="submit" onclick="run()" />

<script>




function run(){


var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('checks');
var str = '';

for (i = 0;i < 3; i++){


      if(checks[i].checked === true){
         str += checks[i].value + " ";
     
}     
   }


     alert(str);



}
</script>
</div>
</html>
```